# how to stick my vertical scrollbar to bottom using onUpdate function in jQuery Scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  $('.scrollbar-dynamic').scrollbar({

                "onUpdate": function (container) {
                    container.animate({ scrollTop: $(container)[0].scrollHeight }, "slow");

                },

            });
```

i am using http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/ plugin .. please help me

when i use this it reinitialize the size and scrolls from top to bottom .. i Want it to stick to bottom on new items added